# Format a date when reading into GridView

Tags: asp.net

I am reading a `Date` from a Table into a `GridView`, and it appears formatted in the `GridView` as:

```
15/01/2012 00:00:00
```

- How can I read it in so that just the date part appears, minus the `00:00:00`?
- And when I use UPDATE, how do I store it back to the Table?

> ```
> <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
>                             <ItemTemplate>
>                                 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SDate") %>' >
>                                 </asp:Label>
>                             </ItemTemplate>
>                             <EditItemTemplate>
>                                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SDate")%>'></asp:TextBox>
>                             </EditItemTemplate>
>                         </asp:TemplateField>
> ```

Comment: Can we see your GridView markup and binding code?

Comment: To get the formatting, just add a second parameter to `Eval()`: `<%# Eval("SDate", "{0:d}") %#>`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a `BoundField` to display the date, it has a property called `DataFormatString` you can set that will format your field to the simple date format you'd like:

```
<asp:BoundField ... DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" ... runat="server" />
```

If you'd doing something with a `TemplateField`, you can specify the date format in the binding expression:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ...>
            <%# Eval(Container.DataItem, "DateProperty", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>
        </asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Because you're only changing how the data is *displayed*, the full underlying date is still available to you when you perform your SQL `UPDATE`, assuming you're retrieving your data via the `DataItem` property of each `GridViewRow`.